# Is the following topology $T_2$?

Tags: general-topology

I would like to know if the topology generated by the following subbase  $S = \tau \cup \{\mathbb{Q}\}$ is $T_2$ where $\tau$ is the standard topology on the real numbers. My intuition says yes since the real numbers with the standard topology is $T_2$, but would like to know how the inclusion of the rational numbers would make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space and is $T_2$ then for every topology $\tau'$ with $\tau\subseteq\tau'$ the topological space $(X,\tau')$ will be $T_2$ as well.

If $u,v$ are distinct elements of $X$ then sets $U,V$ exist having empty intersection  and with $u\in U\in\tau$ and $v\in V\in\tau$.

Then also $u\in U\in\tau'$ and $v\in V\in\tau'$.

Comment: Thank you for the great wisdom, I greatly appreciate it. May I also ask how this new topology would look like?

Comment: Each of its elements is an element of $\tau  $ or has the shape  $U\cap\mathbb Q $ where  $U $ is an element of $\tau $.

Comment: Thank you so much again

Answer (score 1):

If $(X,\tau)$ is topological space and $\tau\subseteq\sigma$ is another topology then $\sigma$ is Hausdorff if $\tau$ is. This simply follows from the observation that if two points can be separated by open subsets in $\tau$ then the same subsets are open in $\sigma$ and so they can be separated in $\sigma$.

So **every** topology containing reals is Hasudorff.

Comment: Thank you for the great wisdom, I greatly appreciate it. May I also ask how this new topology would look like?